# CompilerServices.Operators equivalent on C#

Tags: c#, operators

I want to know if exists namespace available for C#, cause this class come from :

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices
```

cause I want to do something like this, but in C#:

```
Dim m = GetType(CompilerServices.Operators).GetMethod("LikeString")
```

Thanks

Comment: This will be use for Reflection porpouses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it can do that without trouble. You will have to reference the VisualBasic assembly in your C# project.

```
var m = CompilerServices.Operators.GetType().GetMethod("LikeString");
```

Answer (score 0):

[LikeString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.operators.likestring.aspx) is a method that is used by the [Like](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) operator in VB. There's no equivalent operator in c# but you could use [IsMatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0.aspx) to achieve similar functionality:

```
bool bResult = Regex.IsMatch("some input string", "[a-z]*");
```

Comment: His question was very confusing, I wasn't sure if your take on the question or mine was going to be what he was looking for...