# Is there C# version of Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Operators?

Tags: c#, vb.net, operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CompilerServices.Operators equivalent on C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716962/compilerservices-operators-equivalent-on-c)

I was looking for Microsoft.CSharp.CompilerServices.Operators but couldn't find it.

Comment: @Nifle: The accepted answer in that question says to add a reference to the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly to the project, and call `GetMethod()`. I don't think that's what the OP wants.

Comment: @Robert Harvey: but that is the answer to this question or there is only a simple 'No'.
This class uses the Visual Basic Compiler and therefor it doesn't make sense to add it to c# Assembly.

Comment: @Tim, I believe this question is asking "is there an equivalent to operators like `DivideObject` which implement C# semantics vs. VB ones."  In which case it is a different question with potential answers (see mine for an example).

Comment: @Robert is right, I wanted to know this and saw that question but I don't want to use the vb assembly. I was looking to use methods like Operators.OrObject, etc.

Comment: This is just silly.  Yeah, that assembly contains a special kind of IL.  It will leap off the screen and suck half your brains out when you run it.  That VB has supported dynamic dispatch for a very long time and C# just recently caught up is of course fiction as well.

Comment: @Hans: Do you mean this is a huge oversight by MS for C#?

Comment: No, I mean that *you* made a huge oversight.  Especially since you've got an accepted answer from users whose brains appear in tact since it was posted a year ago.

Comment: I don't see how, I said I didn't wanna use the VB assembly, and don't know the internals of how it could be different or same as a potential one for C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no real equivalent to this in the C# runtime assembly.

However many these methods are essentially implementing the late bound operations for VB.Net in a declarative method (and indeed there are cases where the late binder simply just defers to these methods for operations).  So these could be replicated in C# by defining methods which just explicitly defer to the C# dynamic binder.

For example, the rough equivalent of `DivideObject` in C# would be the following

```
public static dynamic DivideObject(dynamic left, dynamic right)
{
    return left / right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jared, so one has to replicate this, right? What's the reason for C# not to have this as VB? Also what if someone has to use pre .NET 4.0? I assume then, one has to use the VB assembly?

Comment: @Joan I'm unsure as to why C# does not have it.  Probably a better question is why did VB expose it in the first place.  Yes to the question about 4.0 .